# Vercel NextJs deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I can't deploy to Vercel by pushing code to main since yesterday. I get this strange error for every page on my website (404, homepage, etc.) even though my application doesn't contain a single useID() hook:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useId')
    at exports.useId (/vercel/path1/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:350)
```

Has anyone else experienced this?
What I have tried:

1. Rolling back to the last commit that worked
2. Deploying without package-lock.json
3. Updating NextJs and React to the latest version

Looks like the build error occurs when after:

```
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
info  - Generating static pages (0/10)  **<- After this line**
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useId')
```

[image]

Comment: My application doesn't use a single useId()

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it started working again... Might have been an issue on their side.